# How to show code outline in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, outline-view

This kind of stuff exists in Eclipse:

[image]

But I've not found it in Visual Studio yet. Is there such a window to show code outline at all?

I tried both Document Outline and Class View windows. The Class View is close, but it only shows class information, can it come up with function info also?

Comment: There is an Outline window, interestingly, present in Visual Studio Code, which is free. One should also note that the feature can somehow be achieved by using Visual Studio combo boxes that stand right above the code editor window.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- not free, but if you install Visual AssistX, each document gets a dropdown box listing all methods in a file (alphabetically or in the order they occur)
- check Class View again, it does show functions (but not per document). Also check out the Code Definition Window, extremely nice when combined with Class View.

Comment: I'm also using Visual AssistX, and I can really recommend it.  It's actually quite essential if you're developing C++ in Visual Studio.

Comment: not that I know of, but as said, Class View is the closest match

Comment: class view should suffice!

Comment: the outline window is interestingly present in Visual Studio Code, which is free.

Answer (score 71):

One great plugin for VS is [CodeMaid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496). It is powerful and it is open source!
You can also sort your methods within the CodeMaid Spade view.

Here is a screenshot.

[image: Code outline]

Comment: May be for the file that I have, CodeMaid Spade is an empty window!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I like the outline of CodeMaid best. It has its own view (in contrast to AxTools) and can be docked everywhere. Just like in Eclipse! Perfect!

Comment: +1! Wow, this is a truly awesome extension. Didn't knew about it. Giving that's free i would say that everybody should at least try it, really.

Comment: The Spade window also doesn't show anything for JS files which is a major bummer.

Comment: @SarjanWebDev I have encountered this too; sometimes Codemaid spade stops showing itself. For now I remedy it by restarting VS2015.

Comment: The keyboard support is horrible though. I wouldn‘t recommend it if you just want to quickly jump to code. Someone asked about keyboard support here https://github.com/codecadwallader/codemaid/issues/447 that has a short explanation but it is not great. Too much pressing of tab to get the focus to the right element when you want to search and then select. Nothing close to Eclipse’s Ctrl+O unfortunately :/

Comment: as @Polshgiant said The Spade doesn't show anything for js files and that is the most important ability I need. On the other hand, I love Spade for splitting code regions and calculating the complexity of the code although can't see anything about how to calculate that or accuracy.

Comment: The Spade window becomes empty for C++ file when we jump to a header file using "Go to Definition" option and that file is present in another Project within the same solution but somehow VS finds that file in "external dependencies". You can check this using "sync with active document" option. The workaround is to close this file then browse to that Project in Solution Explorer and then open the file from there. There is a VS bug for this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/324991/sync-with-active-document-finding-file-in-external.html

Comment: what should i do after i install to see the outline?

Answer (score 60):

Also non-free, but [Jetbrains Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) provides a [File Structure Window](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Windows__File_Structure_Window.html), what perhaps is what you are searching for.

To display this dockable window, select from the menu: ReSharper → Windows → File Structure (default shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've owned Resharper for many years and never knew about this feature!

Answer (score 59):

This question was asked quite a while ago and before Visual Studio Code existed but I found it when searching for how to do this with Visual Studio Code so I thought others might stumble on this question too so I thought I'd share my solution. Here's how to do it in Visual Studio Code. I'm using TypeScript but it works for JavaScript, too.

1) View -> Open View

[image]

2) select (or type) Outline

[image]

3) You'll now get an Outline palette that shows full information on the class including properties and functions.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I found the same.  But now I need to collapse to just the functions/methods names.  I don't want to list all of the properties.  Any ideas????   The editor keeps reverting to displaying the properties, I click the 'Collapse all' button which I found, but I would like an user setting to default to 'collapse all'.

Comment: I haven't found a way to keep them collapsed all the time.

Comment: I just found it!  Uninstall "PHP Intellephense" and install the extension "PHP IntelliSense".  It shows a list of functions in the outline and is also less invasive during code completion - I like it better.

Comment: That's great that you found it. I don't use PHP with VS Code - I'm using TypeScript so I don't think that will work for me.

Comment: This is **VS code**. The question is about **Visual Studio**.

Answer (score 21):

In newer Visual Studio versions (e.g. 2015) you can see this directly in the solution explorer. Simply expand the .cs file and you will get the list of the methods in the order they are listed in the file. This is exactly the same as the Outline in Eclipse.

If you want to see the stuff alphabetically, open the file and between the tab pane and the editor, there is a row showing the project name, the class name with namespace, and a drop down with the available methods and properties.

Comment: This is cool, except Form classes only expand to show the associated files (.resx and .designer.cs), and don't show the class info.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the Class View Window, or you can use outlining to collapse the code window to definitions (Ctrl-M-O and Ctrl M-L in the standard keyboard set up)

Comment: This is super helpful. Thank you for sharing. But it doesn't quite scratch the same cognitive itch IMO.

Answer (score 9):

Trick is to call Ctrl+F2, then Tab, then Tab, then Down arrow. I've done it with this simple AutoHotkey script when I hit Ctrl+o:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe devenv.exe
^o::
  Send ^{F2}
  Send {Tab}
  Send {Tab}
  Send {Down}
  return
#IfWinActive
```

It will show dropdown that is closest to Quick Outline in Eclipse or others.

[image: Outline]

Comment: Creative solution :)

Comment: But it dose not suitable for cpp files which contains different classes or namespaces :(

Answer (score 6):

There is now a free add-in available through the add-in manager in VS2010 that works quite well. It also has a dark theme.

[VS10x Code Map v2](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1c54d1bd-d898-4705-903f-fa4a319b50f2)

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot of the code map]

Comment: Free for 30 days, but operates with limited functionality thereafter. Having said that... it's very reasonable. See: [http://www.axtools.com/purchase.php](http://www.axtools.com/purchase.php)

Answer (score 6):

Go To "Solution Explorer" and select your project; then select a class file you want to outline, then expand the little triangle just below that class (as shown in the figure below)

[image: code outline in visual studio]

Comment: ah the secret is to then choose "scope to this" from the context menu

Answer (score 5):

In VS2017 you can navigate between items in the file directly from the upper right corner of the Editor.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Ctrl+F2 then Tab and again Tab to access it via keyboard

Comment: Thanks! I am relatively new to VS and being the GUI very densely populated I did not find it yet. A dedicated tab would be even more useful.

Answer (score 2):

you can have document outline window by going to view-> Other Window -> Document Outline or you can have it using Ctrl+W, U
I am using VS-2008. You can have a look at the following links also:

- http://wildermuth.com/2008/06/06/The_Document_Outline_in_Visual_Studio_2008
- http://dotnetkicks.com/tipsandtricks/Visual_Studio_2008_Document_Outline_Split_View

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

// 2019 answer
There is an free extension for Visual Studio that provide code outline: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamirBoulema.CodeNav
[image]

Comment: It doesn't support C++.

Answer (score 1):

I've started using [VSCommands 10](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf?SRC=Home).

This has support for the most common languages used when developing in Visual Studio 2010, including JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

There's an extension provided Free, by Microsoft, that enables this and many other features into Visual Studio. The extension is [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/).

Comment: I cannot find such outline window in Productivity Power Tools.

Comment: @xmedeko, it is not an additional window, it enhances the Solution Explorer to work the way it started working as of VS2012 where it displays the class and its members on each file.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+Shift+O` comes closest to what you want

If you need more, see: [discussion of the Outline Feature on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5605)

Comment: Note: this is a solution for VSCode while OP asked about Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP, make sure you install full version as mentioned in the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php#_linting)

Answer (score -2):

Resharper has a feature of inspection. You can see incoming and outgoing calls from there.

shortcut: CTRL+ Shift + ALT +

Answer (score -2):

A list of things you can use:
1.Visual Studio default's ClassView
2.Visual Assist's VA OUTLINE Feature
3.CodeMaid's Spade Feature

Answer (score -2):

In Visual Studio Code, the popup outline is not called outline but symbol list. The command is "Go to Symbol in Editor...", and default shortcut is "Ctrl + Shift + O".
Checked again, the question is to Visual Studio, I guess it could be same with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: So when the question was for Visual Studio, why did you answer for totally unrelated Visual Studio Code?