# Visual Studio variables/methods outline and dropdown options?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Eclipse has something like this showing you the outlines of method declarations, imports, variables...

[image: Outline]

Is there something similar in Visual Studio 2010? I can't seem to find it.

Another thing is the context menu dropdowns.

In Visual Studio, I have to click on the underlined word:

[image]

And wait for that little blue underscore to pop up then I have to carefully hover over it like so:

[image]

for the drop down menu to pop up.  Then I have to click on it to bring up the options.

In Eclipse I can hover over the underlined word and get the options about half a sec later OR hover over it and press F2 immediately to get the options.

Does anyone know if such features are available in VS2010?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show code outline in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793892/how-to-show-code-outline-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, there is a window called "Class View" that may be similar to what you want. You can access it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

For your second question, if your cursor is on the identifier that is underlined, you can type either of the following in order to open that same context menu:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> *(that's a period or dot)*
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>

Comment: Alt+Shift+F10 works.  Do you happen to know the name of this action in options > Keyboard?

Comment: @Jack Unfortunately no I don't. I just found out ctrl-'.' ( control-period ) also opens that context menu, which is slightly less work.