# Visual Studio "document outline" for C# file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file-structure, outline-view

In **Visual Studio** (2013/2015/2017), the **Document Outline window** for **C#** files is always empty ("There are no items to show for the selected document.").
It seems that this functionality is not (not yet / no more) implemented.

But then, how do I view the structure of the file? Is there any extension which implements this functionality?

- showing only the selected/opened file
- show regions
- move/rename members
- show documentation

*Using the Solution Explorer and Class View are NOT the solution.*
In the old Visual Studio 2003, I did use a self written Add-In, because it was easy to read the structure. (There were also other tools but I cannot find them anymore). So I ask here which solution you know. :-)

EDIT: Similar question also found:
[How to show code outline in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793892/how-to-show-code-outline-in-visual-studio)

**UPDATE: After 10 years the feature has finally arrived in VS 2022**

Comment: I never understood the purpose of features like this. There's a *huge* code viewer window designed to let you "view the structure of the file". Why would you need some small, auxiliary view? If you can't figure out the outline of the code at a glance, it is poorly formatted.

Comment: Microsoft has developed the outline window to get a fast overview and fast navigation. So we don't need to discus about the purpose. I don't need an extra tool I would use the existing one, but it is not implemented for C# (and also for other files)

Comment: Disabled now in 17.4.4 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#17.4.4

Comment: @MarkD Do you happen to know why it is now disabled?

Comment: No - I tried to look around but did not see anything obvious in search results - I just saw the announcement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*The best solution I found at present is:*

**JetBrains ReSharper** (v8.0+) has a **File Structure window** which shows the structure of the current file as tree (types/members) and regions are also supported.

[image: *.cs]

[image: App.xaml]

[image: App.config]

Comment: If you're going to mention a 3rd party product, you should mention it has a price tag.

Comment: I dit not ask for free solution, but you are right, ReSharper is a non-free solution _for users which not already have ReSharper :-)_

Answer (score 17):

This feature has been added in [Visual Studio 2022 17.4.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#summary-of-whats-new-in-this-release-of-visual-studio-2022-version-174):

> You can now easily view a file’s structure at a glance in the Document Outline window. The Document Outline window displays the symbol tree of the file in the editor helping you quickly navigate and edit project files. You can open Document Outline by going to *View* > *Other Windows* > *Document Outline* or by using the shortcut *Ctrl+Alt+T*.

---

**Update:** This feature [was disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#1744--visual-studio-2022-version-1744) in v17.4.4 for [the following reason](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/document-outline-function-so-slow/10201114):

> After we released 17.4, we found some significant performance problems with the C# implementation of Document Outline that we didn’t catch during preview usage. We’ve temporarily disabled the feature, and are spending more time working on it to address these issues. These changes are larger than we’d usually like to include in a revision release, and need more bake time, so 17.4.3 [sic] onwards & 17.5 will both ship with the feature disabled. I know this is disappointing, but we have it back in no time and enabled in a future VS update.

Comment: Ohh, I have not even noticed. Thanks. It took 10 years of development time ;-)

Comment: @kux: I noticed it in the Release Notes, asked myself *"Why in the world would I need this? I can already see this information in Solution Explorer!"*, googled for "Document Outline" to find more information, and, thus, stumbled upon your question.

Comment: Just because you don't know what you're going to use it for doesn't mean no one knows or needs it. I don't understand why some still think they are the center of the world ;-) There are good reasons to use this. For example, I use it to easily structure my file. Sure, there is another way, otherwise you had not been able to work for the last 10 years, but it is easier that way.

Comment: In version 17.2.6 this is also already available, so the release note are to late ;-)

Comment: @kux: I didn't want to imply that no one needed it - if that were the case, MS would not have spent time implementing it. ;-) My question was one of genuine curiosity, since the release notes did not make clear to me what I could do with the new window that I couldn't already do with the Solution Explorer window.

Comment: (a) In Document outline, you have always the current file, The Solution explorer has all files. but you have to expand. and the more you expand, the more confusing the solution explorer becomes. whereas it is already confusing for larger projects without file contens. So 2 lists are better as one tree. one for the solution, one for the current file. (b)  In document outline you can move members and this without selecting the code first.

Comment: Amazing, that I saw this in the release notes, forget where it was, spent ages looking, turned to google and eventually dug up this answer.  Thank you!

Comment: In version 17.4.4 they disabled it again! Does anyone know why?

Comment: @VladislavBorovikov: Because [it's buggy](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/document-outline-function-so-slow/10201114) and they need more time to fix it. I'll update my answer with details.

Answer (score 15):

There is also [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/) which provides the same functionality as JetBrains Resharper, but is **free**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 for a matching alternative. 
(compared with ReSharper, it seems to work only for code files)

Answer (score 5):

If you don´t have ReSharper, you can´t miss the **Productivity Power Tools**, made by Microsoft itself.

There's a specific version for each of Visual Studio versions. More info on these links:

- [VS2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace?SRC=Home)
- [VS2012](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd)
- [VS2010](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99)

They have a feature called Solution Navigator
[image: Solution Navigator]

Also, there's this one that seems very interesting for bring alot of cool customizations to Visual Studio IDE, called **VSCommands**. It's worth to checkout their website => http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/features

Comment: +100! Sadly, it is VERY easy to miss this addon. Why is it not included with the IDE? Some of these featues are a must-have for any simple IDE.

Comment: VSCommands.squaredinfinity.com site is offline.  Look hear for existing codebase/comments on status of project but as of today, project appears dead as well: https://github.com/squaredinfinity/VSCommands

Answer (score 4):

It helps you look at the nested structure of certain types of files, e.g. windows forms designer file, open a form designer you should see all controls on the form shown in nested structure in the document outline window.