# VS Code - Open the Project Explorer one level deeper to show classes

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to open VS-Code's tree-view Project Explorer one level deeper to show, not only the files but the actual classes present in each file (...and as an added bonus, another lever deeper the functions/methods present in each class)

Example Project Explorer: 
[image]

I tried the bookmarks extension but it gets messy and it is not sorted in a structured tree as the Project Explorer is

Comment: Where is the Project Explorer?

Comment: I added a screenshot, see the red circle

Comment: it is a File Explorer, use the OUTLINE view to see the classes of the current file

Comment: Thanks it gives even more detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793892/how-to-show-code-outline-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found and tried this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oleg-shilo.codemap

I think this is what you are searching:
[image]

Anyways you can search "vs code outline extension" on google or in another searcher

Comment: looks a lot like the OUTLINE view in the Explorer bar

Comment: More or less, but it shows you more information, if you have longer programmes you can see that is more helpful!